# Laravel sync not working after i call update

Tags: laravel, model, synchronization, pivot

I'm trying to sync my pivot table but I get a column 'article_id' cannot be null. everything works fine except the **Update** function when I call **sync**.

> Article model:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', "tag_article", "article_id");
}
```

> Tag model:

```
public function article()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article', "tag_article", "tag_id");
}
```

> Pivot table:

```
Schema::create('tag_article', function (Blueprint $table) {
        
        $table->bigInteger('tag_id')->unsigned()->index();

        $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->bigInteger('article_id')->unsigned()->index();

        $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

> Controller:

```
public function create(){

    $tags = Tag::pluck('name', 'id');

    return view('create', compact('tags'));
}

public function store(CreateArticleRequest $request){

    $article = article::create($request->all());

    $article->tags()->attach($request->input('tag_list'));

    return redirect('create');
}

public function edit(Article $Article){

    $tags = Tag::pluck('name', 'id');

    return view('edit', compact('article', 'tags'));

}

public function update(Article $article, CreateArticleRequest $request){

    $article->update($request->all());

    $article->tags()->sync($request->input('tag_list'));

    return redirect('create');

}
```

> The tag ids I send to sync:

```
array:2 [▼
   0 => "14"
   1 => "16"
]
```

> The error i get:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
1048 Column 'article_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `tag_article` (`article_id`, `tag_id`) values (?, 14))
```

> PS: I can't call **attach** or **detach** in **Update method** either (same error)

Can anyone explain what is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what does your `update` route definition look like?

Comment: @lagbox thank you, I never thought about the route. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @lagbox I fix my problem

I changed my route from:

```
Route::patch('/update', 'ArticleController@update')->name('update');
```

To:

```
Route::patch('/update/{article}', 'ArticleController@update')->name('update');
```

and changed my form::open from:

```
{!! Form::model($article, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => 'update']) !!}
```

To:

```
{!! Form::model($article, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => ['update', $article->id]]) !!}
```